# Why is `submission.permalink` with PRAW working - even if I can't find anything about this attribute in the source code?

Tags: python, reddit, praw

I was looking for an attribute which contains the submission title which is part of the permalink of a submission. Unfortunately, `praw.models.reddit.submission.Submission` doesn't seem to contain a `permalink` attribute, according to PRAW docs http://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/search.html?q=permalink&check_keywords=yes&area=default

However, if I run

```
import praw
print(praw.__version__)
reddit = praw.Reddit(...)
for submission in reddit.subreddit("redditdev").hot(limit=5):
    print(type(submission), submission.permalink)
```

I'll get

> ```
> 4.4.0
> <class 'praw.models.reddit.submission.Submission'> /r/redditdev/comments/77gz1m/new_mobile_friendly_reddit_search_is_now_in_beta/
> <class 'praw.models.reddit.submission.Submission'> /r/redditdev/comments/77dkl6/can_anyone_explain_why_my_if_x_in_y_isnt_working/
> <class 'praw.models.reddit.submission.Submission'> /r/redditdev/comments/77ci3v/ratelimit_you_are_doing_that_too_much/
> <class 'praw.models.reddit.submission.Submission'> /r/redditdev/comments/77bak9/is_there_some_standard_way_to_host_bots/
> <class 'praw.models.reddit.submission.Submission'> /r/redditdev/comments/77ci1v/praw_checking_if_my_bot_has_already_posted_in_a/
> ```

So my call to `permalink` works fine, even if `grep` can't find `permalink` in source files other than `comment.py`?!

> ```
> $ grep -r -i -l "permalink" --include "*.py" /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/praw/
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/praw/models/reddit/comment.py
> ```

It's the same with the latest version, if you're searching for `permalink` in the source on GitHub: https://github.com/praw-dev/praw/search?l=Python&q=permalink&type=&utf8=%E2%9C%93

What's going on? Where does the attribute come from?

Comment: All I've got is a vague hand-wavy "inheritance". :) But exactly why, not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PRAW dynamically provides the attributes that Reddit returns via the API. Because those attributes are subject to change on Reddit's end, PRAW makes no effort to document them, other than to instruct you on how to discover what is available:

https://praw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started/quick_start.html#determine-available-attributes-of-an-object

When you iterate over `reddit.subreddit("redditdev").hot(limit=5)` PRAW makes a request to https://oauth.reddit.com/r/redditdev/hot/.json?limit=5, which essentially returns the same data as https://www.reddit.com/r/redditdev/hot/.json?limit=5. When visiting the latter link, you should see the permalink attribute appear 5 times, because the request is for 5 submissions. You will also see all the other attributes available for submission objects.

Comment: I am always open to ways to improve the documentation. Would you car to make a pull request for it?

Comment: You're awesome.